# Comparing two large SQL queries

Tags: sql

I am replacing an old untidy SQL query with a new version, because it was failing to include several rows it should have.

The new query certainly includes these missing rows, but I want to be entirely sure that it also includes all of the rows from the original query.

The two queries use entirely different tables. Each query is ~14000 rows.

Is there a query I can write that checks whether QueryA contains any rows that QueryB does not have?

Comment: Can you tell us what the Primary Key columns are?  Which fields in each query are unique to each row.

Comment: Sorry. Both queries only return one field. Obviously it's got the same name in both. This field contains no duplicate values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
Select  * FROM 
(
QUERY A GOES HERE 
) AS A
LEFT JOIN
(
QUERY B GOES HERE 
) AS B
ON A.Col1=B.Col1 AND A.Col2=B.Col2 ....
WHERE B.Col1 IS NULL
```

You can either include all the columns in the "on clause" or you can just include the columns you need to ensure the rows are the same, such as the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that both queries returns the primary key column from the same table:

```
select *
from (QueryA) a
where a.PK not in (select PK from (QueryB) b)
```

Please note that the parantheses means that these are subqueries.

Comment: A complex query is unlikely to have a single field unique identifier in the result set.

Comment: Unlikely doesn't mean it's true.

Comment: You also need to compare both directions.  What if `QueryB` had results that `QueryA` does not?  This won't show the exceptions.

Comment: Turns out it does only have one field so this one will work fine.

Comment: In this case it does- good guess. This looks like the right kind of thing. But it is taking forever to run- I've left it for 5 mins now.

Comment: @JNK You're right, but the question only asks for rows in QueryA that are missing in QueryB, not the other way around.

Comment: Still, it's better to check all columns of a row in this case (which is more of code testing), just to be sure that all works as designed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the results from the old query into a temp table.
2. Select the results from the new query into another temp table.
3. Outer join from one table to the other, equating all the columns.
4. Add a where clause to only return rows where there are nulls on one side or the other.

For example, if the results looked like (theoretically):

```
UserId | FirstName | LastName | Email
```

Then run each query into a separate temp table with the same structure, say `#resOld` and '#resNew'.

Then:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM #resOld OLD

LEFT OUTER JOIN #redNew NEW -- LEFT OUTER JOIN, so we still retain rows which don't match
    ON  NEW.UserId    = OLD.UserId
    AND NEW.FirstName = OLD.FirstName
    AND NEW.LastName  = OLD.LastName
    AND NEW.Email     = OLD.Email

WHERE OLD.UserID IS NULL -- Only retain rows where we didn't match. Can use any field from OLD which cannot be null by design.
```

This query will only return rows when there are rows from one results set which don't match rows in the other.

**EDIT:** That is more complicated than it needs to be, you can just invert the join criteria and remove the WHERE like so:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM #resOld OLD

INNER JOIN #redNew NEW -- Inner join where rows are different.
    ON  NEW.UserId    != OLD.UserId
    AND NEW.FirstName != OLD.FirstName
    AND NEW.LastName  != OLD.LastName
    AND NEW.Email     != OLD.Email
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ( < put query 1 here > ) AS Query1
LEFT JOIN
  ( < put query 2 here > ) AS Query2
    ON  Query1.Field1 = Query2.Field1
    AND Query1.Field2 = Query2.Field2
    AND Query1.Field3 = Query2.Field3
    etc, etc
WHERE
  Query2.Field1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to get it into SQL Server, you can just do:

```
<Query 1>
EXCEPT
<Query 2>

<Query 2>
EXCEPT
<Query 1>
```

This will only output records that don't exist in the other query.  It checks all fields in the result sets.

I included both directions since if there are more records in the lower part of the `EXCEPT` statement those don't get shown as exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use a Union of QueryA and QueryB and Group By.

See an example of that here:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx on Jeff's SQL server blog.

Comment: This compares two _tables_, not _queries_.